# File Contents Replaced with 0xFF (and a few 0x7F)

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, virus, file-corruption, binary-files

I have a corrupted word document whose data I am trying to recover. It comes from a thumb drive suspected of having virus activity; this is not the only file that has been affected. Opened it up with a binary editor and the whole thing is full of `0xFF` and the occasional `0x7F`. So it looks like a virus got a hold of it and steamrolled it. Questions are

1. Am I misreading this - is there possibly some information tucked away I'm just not seeing, like past the normal file boundary
2. What kind of a virus does this? Don't think I've run across this particular beastie
3. Is this even a virus at all, or just some run of the mill file corruption failure mode?

Any insights welcome.

Comment: provide more details. 'recovered' from what? what type of drive is the file stored on? are other files affected too?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen edited, thanks.

Comment: So all the data was replaced with 0xFF, yeah, your data is gone unless you had File History enabled (and that’s trivial for malware to disable). You have provided enough information to identify anything about the malware except it was destructive. Scan the drive on a machine isolated from your network

Comment: If the file was emailed to you and is nothing but FF an 7F then there is nothing in it for you to recover. There is a possibility of scanning the memory stick itself using something like [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) where you might get lucky.

Comment: I suspect it's not a virus but a cheapo USB flash drive where NAND is bleeding data or having some firmware issue. Either data itself is corrupt or FAT is. Best is to image the drive and put it aside, and see if you can recover anything from the disk image using for example DMDE, look in RAW results rather than the folder tree. https://youtu.be/32GJr39O744

Comment: @JoepvanSteen that very well could be the case, thanks. I actually don't have the device on me, just a copy of the file. I've advised leaving it alone till I can try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is filled with byte pattern like FF FF FF then there's nothing you can recover from this file.

However since this is happening on a USB flash drive I'd like to add the following:

NAND memory bleeds data and have witnessed the following happening on multiple occasions on cheap flash drives.

- Corruption inside files themselves. So IOW, the sectors storing the file data 'corrupted.
- However I have also seen file corruption due to file system corruption.

In the first case there's nothing you can do. If however file content is intact but not referred to correctly files may appear corrupt. I must add that the *entire* file containing nonsense data makes me lean towards the file itself being corrupt.

What you can try is 'carve' the drive for file content. You can do this using virtually any file recovery tool, PhotoRec is an option, my personal goto tool is DMDE.

[image]

It's wise to work from a disk image rather than scanning the drive directly, example: https://youtu.be/32GJr39O744